# Dynamic Ipython Accordion Widget

Tags: python, widget, accordion, jupyter-notebook

Thought it'd be cool to keep track of items selected from a list in a dynamically generated accordion menu that offers subsequent options. Populating an ipython accordion widget on the fly was relatively simple (though maybe I should be using linked widgets?), however upon every new addition the previously selected item in the accordion toggles its visibility. Needless to say, it's quite distracting.

Does anyone else get the same issue? And if so, is there a way to alter the visibility of accordion items, for instance ensuring the latest addition is always "selected" and visible? I'm using Ipython 3.0 and ipython notebook 3.1.0

```
from IPython.html import widgets 
from IPython.display import display 
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        caption = widgets.Latex(value = 'Select a fruit')
        w = widgets.Select(
            description="Fruits",
            options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears']
        )
        w.on_trait_change(self.change_selection, 'value')

        self.ac_cont = widgets.Box(children = [dd])
        self.accordion = widgets.Accordion(
            children = [],
            )
        display(caption, w, self.accordion)

    def change_selection(self, name, value):
        self.accordion.children = tuple(list(self.accordion.children) + [self.ac_cont])
        print len(self.accordion.children), value
        self.accordion.set_title(len(self.accordion.children)-1, value)

Test()
```